# Is Wittgenstein's proposition "the world is a collection of facts not things" similar to Hegel's claim that objects are not things but forces?

Tags: wittgenstein, analytic-philosophy, hegel, continental-philosophy

They both seem to suggest that objects are not defined by their discrete appearances but rather by the conceptual framework which allows us to perceive them. In case of Wittgenstein the world is all that is the case whereas in case of Hegel, via the thesis, the negation of the thesis and then the negation of the negation we are able to understand things. This means things are not objects but rather the process we go through to understand them ?

Comment: IMO the statement "that objects are not defined by their discrete appearances but rather by the conceptual framework which allows us to perceive them" is not a correct reading of Wittgenstein. W's statement: "the world is a collection of facts not things" means that the "source" of meaning is not the correspondence between names and objects but that between sentences and *facts*, i.e. objects+relations.

Comment: @Ash Rivers Please give a reference concerning Hegel: Where does Hegel claim that objects are forces? - In the heading of your question you speak about forces while in the body you speak about a process. But force and process are quite different things.

Comment: @JoWehler https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiL6nXT4GPw&t=2724s

Because the mind alternates between the unity and the multiplicity of an object while trying to perceive it objects are force. That's what I meant. The alternating of the mind is what I called "process" although not accurate i guess

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hegel says a similar thing though?(although obviously im a beginner which is why im clarifying) The way the mind perceives things is via objects+relations (identity of identify indifference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly a similarity between Wittgenstein's claim that the world is a collection of facts, not things, and Hegel's claim that objects are not things but forces. Both suggest that our understanding of objects is shaped by a conceptual framework, and that this framework is more important than the discrete appearances of objects.

However, there are also some important differences between the two claims. For Wittgenstein, the world is all that is the case, which means that our understanding of the world is shaped by the totality of facts. For Hegel, on the other hand, objects are only understandable within the context of a dialectical process, whereby we move from thesis to antithesis to synthesis. This suggests that our understanding of things is not static, but rather dynamic and constantly evolving.